# How to get the position of a div relative to window in angular2 html?

Tags: angular

I have the following:

[image]

I want to be able to get the position of div1 relative to the entire document. (it is nested within a "middle-of-page-div"). How do I do this in angular? I have:

> @ViewChild('div1') div1;

Though div1.offsetTop appears to be 0...

Comment: try `this.div1.nativeElement.....`

Comment: this.div1.nativeElement.offsetTop is 0 and same goes for scrollTop. Am looking for the position of the element "offset from the top of the window/document"

Comment: `this.div1.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY`
Try the above code

Comment: window.scrollY = 0 and this.div1......getBoundingClientRect().top also equals 0

Comment: create a plunker

Comment: @Rolando are you running your code during `ngAfterViewInit()` ? If not try running your logic when it hits `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: Yes, unfortunately...